# Pandas: merge columns with the similar names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
Politics  Politics  Politics    Arts/Culture  Arts/Culture  Arts/Culture
  nan       nan        c         nan            nan          c
  nan        b         nan        a             nan          nan
  nan        b         nan        a             nan          nan
  a          nan       nan        nan           c            nan
```

Basically, this goes on throughout the dataframe.
I want to merge the similar columns to the dataframe below

```
Politics    Arts/Culture  
 c              c
 b              a
 b              a
 a              c
```

Comment: Are the column names actually similair or the same? I know by default pandas would rename such columns on import unless you've declared your columns manually or via some function.

Comment: They are the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().unstack()
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

  Arts/Culture Politics
0            c        c
1            a        b
2            a        b
3            c        a
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `groupby` with `level=0` and `axis=1` then do `first`

```
s=df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).first()
  Arts/Culture Politics
0            c        c
1            a        b
2            a        b
3            c        a
```